# How to sort multiple rows from Lowest to Highest value?

Tags: linux, sorting, awk

I'm attempting to take several datasets with over 800 rows and sort each row from the lowest to the highest value. Each line in the data is for one gene/set of variants (chromosome:position_reference/alternative, for example 22:42721284_C/T), separated by tab. The first element in each line is the gene (for example gene1, gene2, gene3 etc), and the rest of the line is for variant ids written in the form 22:42721284_C/T. How many variants there is for each gene will vary. 
The file I have is sorted from highest to lowest position (42721284, 42721258, 42721203) right now, but I want to sort the file from the lowest to highest position.

My file:

```
Gene1 22:42721284_C/T 22:42721258_A/G 22:42721203_A/G …etc
Gene2 22:50483983_C/T 22:50483960_C/G 22:50483951_C/T …etc
Gene3 22:24429129_A/G 22:24428893_A/G 22:24428885_C/T …etc
```

I have tried different black commands (for example black -V), but I am not getting the output from lowest to highest. I would prefer an awk (or gawk) solution, but I am totally new to coding, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Desired output:

```
Gene1 22:42721203_A/G 22:42721258_A/G 22:42721284_C/T …etc
Gene2 22:50483951_C/T 22:50483960_C/G 22:50483983_C/T …etc 
Gene3 22:24428885_C/T 22:24428893_A/G 22:24429129_A/G …etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk for asort():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
    sub("^[^"FS"]*"FS,"")
    split($0,vars)
    n = asort(vars)
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", vars[i], (i<n ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Gene1   22:42721203_A/G 22:42721258_A/G 22:42721284_C/T …etc
Gene2   22:50483951_C/T 22:50483960_C/G 22:50483983_C/T …etc
Gene3   22:24428885_C/T 22:24428893_A/G 22:24429129_A/G …etc
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

- `xargs` for each line in file run
- `sh -c` a shell script
- `first="$1"; shift` save the first argument for later
- `printf "%s\n" "$@"` - print the rest of arguments on separate lines
- `sort` - sort alphabetically
- `tr "\n" " " | sed "s/ $//"` - replace newlines with spaces and remove the trailing newline.
- print output with printf

The script:

```
cat <<EOF >file
Gene1 22:42721284_C/T 22:42721258_A/G 22:42721203_A/G
Gene2 22:50483983_C/T 22:50483960_C/G 22:50483951_C/T
Gene3 22:24429129_A/G 22:24428893_A/G 22:24428885_C/T
EOF

<file xargs -l -P1 sh -c '
    first=$1
    shift
    printf "%s %s\n" "$first" "$(
        printf "%s\n" "$@" |
        sort |
        tr "\n" " " | sed "s/ $//"
    )"
' -- >output

# the same using plain bash while read loop
if false; then
while IFS=' ' read -r first rest; do
    echo "$first" "$(
        <<<"$rest" tr ' ' '\n' |
        sort |
        tr "\n" " " | sed "s/ $//"
    )"
done <file >output
fi

cat <<EOF >expected
Gene1 22:42721203_A/G 22:42721258_A/G 22:42721284_C/T
Gene2 22:50483951_C/T 22:50483960_C/G 22:50483983_C/T
Gene3 22:24428885_C/T 22:24428893_A/G 22:24429129_A/G
EOF

diff output expected
```